Type assertion vs return type in TS reduce with array initializer
Initializer type defined as a utility type in reduce works but type assertion and type inference fail.
Should there be any difference between specifying the type in the initializer, the reduce return type, or type asserting the return of the reduce?
Why does the type inference fail here? Shouldn't specifying the type anywhere have the same effect?
Code:
const sequenceFrequency = {a: 3, b: 5, c: 1};

console.log(Object
    .entries(sequenceFrequency)
    .reduce<[number, string]>(([maxFrequency, maxSequence], [sequence, frequency]) =>
        frequency > maxFrequency ? [frequency, sequence ] : [maxFrequency, maxSequence]
    , [0, ""])
);

console.log(Object
    .entries(sequenceFrequency)
    .reduce(([maxFrequency, maxSequence], [sequence, frequency]) =>
        frequency > maxFrequency ? [frequency, sequence ] : [maxFrequency, maxSequence]
    , [0, ""]) as [number, string]
);

I've read this and this and they should be the same from what I could gather.
Error code
console.log(Object
    .entries(sequenceFrequency)
    .reduce(([maxFrequency, maxSequence], [sequence, frequency]) =>
        frequency > maxFrequency ? [frequency, sequence ] : [maxFrequency, maxSequence]
    , [0, ""] as [number, string])
);

No overload matches this call.
console.log(Object
    .entries(sequenceFrequency)
    .reduce(([maxFrequency, maxSequence], [sequence, frequency]) =>
        frequency > maxFrequency ? [frequency, sequence ] : [maxFrequency, maxSequence]
    , [0, ""])
);

Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string | number'.(2365)
Playground Link.

See this question and ms/TS#42201. reduce() has multiple call signatures and if your initial value is of a type similar enough to the array type then TS will first try to use the nongeneric call signature.  If you manually specify the type parameter then you get the generic one. Add to that the fact that array literals tend to be inferred as unordered arrays and not as tuples, and you get the wackiness you see here. Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something?

It does. Thank you. Sorry for missing that question. Searching failed me.
.reduce(([maxFrequency, maxSequence], [sequence, frequency]) =>
      frequency > maxFrequency ? [frequency, sequence] as [number, string] : [maxFrequency, maxSequence] as [number, string]
    , [0, ""] as [number, string])

This forces the recognition of the array literals as tuples. It's ugly so specifying the generic type parameter is the way to go imo.
